# T-SQL LIKE '%<text>%' issue

Tags: sql-server-2012

Using SQL Server 2012 (11.0.2100.60)

I have constructed a query matching a varchar column using the LIKE and wildcard character %.
The issue I ran into was when the text I was looking for ended the text in the 
The code:
{CASE WHEN _1628 LIKE '%school%' THEN ....}

When the value in _1628 was 'Property Tax - School' it was not matching!

Has anyone seen this before?  I easily put together a workaround, but this doesn't make sense to me?

Comment: maybe you are using a case sensitive collation for that column/table/database

Comment: You don't happen to have the server / connection collation set to Case Sensitive do you?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have case sensitive collation turned on, you can confirm that by running

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('collation')
```

If the return value has CS in there, then you have a case sensitive collation.

You can change it to a case insensitive one:

```
USE master;  
GO  
ALTER DATABASE YourDatabase  
COLLATE NewCollation;  
GO
```

Where NewCollation is the same as your previous one but you have changed CS to CI.

If you do not want to change the collation you can convert both sides of your statement to upper as such

```
CASE WHEN UPPER(_1628) LIKE '%SCHOOL%' THEN ....
```

However, you will take a performance hit with this as the UPPER function will need to called for each row, resulting in a table scan